# How to choose the correct NN model if the metrics are different in training and test time?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, model-evaluations

I am trying to build an LSTM model which has a lot of Dropout and Batch Norm Layers. When I run `model.fit`, the accuracy comes out to around 0.7 on the training data. But when I run `model.evaluate` on the training data, the accuracy is only 0.54.

I understand the training and test metrics are calculated differently due to the dropout and batch norm layers. Is there a way to choose the model based on the metrics computed by `model.evaluate`? Ideally, I would want to choose the model which has high train accuracy and valid accuracy but the train accuracy given by the model is not the correct one. So I would be choosing a model that has high valid accuracy which might be due to chance.